# Need help about a really difficult explanation of a science fiction term (霊子反応 / Spiritual Particles Reaction ??)

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english, video-games, fiction

[image]

**I'm reading a game with science fiction theme, and there is 1 part I don't understand what the F was the writer trying to conveys here, so much thanks if anyone can even decipher what he wrote here (or correct me If I was wrong)**

霊子反応 ( Spiritual Particles Reaction)

精神、もしくは霊的な素粒子。
(Spirit Particles or Spiritual Elementary Particles)

一定したペクトルのエネルギーをもっており、生物の精神的な要素によって反応する特性を持つ。
It has stable/fixed energy's vector (?), and characteristic of reacting according to the spiritual element of the living organism.(??)

精神感応触媒などを介す事によって、任意に霊子を操作し、物理現象などに対し作用して不可思議な事象を起こすことが出来る。
Through a telepathic catalyst or the like (?), it is possible to arbitrarily manipulate Spiritual Particles and and cause mysterious phenomena by acting on physical phenomena.(???)

Comment: Your translation seems to be basically on-point, despite the strange "woo-woo" explanation of the text (that's on the author, not on you ).  Minor points: 精神 isn't "spirit particle", but rather just "spirit", or alternatively "mind; will; motive; mentality; anima"; エネルギーベクトル is just "energy vector", not "energy's vector". As a side note, the author used the term 介【かい】す in a Classical Japanese conjugation, probably to try to sound formal, but in using this attributively (to modify a noun), I think it should be conjugated as 介【かい】する instead.

Comment: All that said, your post doesn't seem to have any specific question -- it sounds instead like you're asking us to proofread, which is out of scope for the Japanese Stack Exchange.  See also [**"We don't do translations or proofreading"**](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799).  If you have a specific question, please edit your post to clarify.  Otherwise, I suspect this thread might get closed as "off-topic".

Comment: Can I ask the title of the game? Just curious what type of object is used in the game...

Comment: sure , i know about this game through an youtuber posting video game music ,and i have to says the music in this game is very good (modern EDM like Initial D car racing anime) . https://vndb.org/v21465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how magic might be explained using scientific terms when a day comes when science can understand magic. You have parsed the sentences mostly correctly, but it may be difficult to make sense of them unless you are familiar with both fantasy and scientific terms.

- **霊子**: Perhaps this should be translated as "spiriton" using the [English suffix *-on*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-on#Suffix), but a similar concept is better known as *mana* in typical fantasy works.
- **一定したベクトルのエネルギー**: It says "fixed vector's energy", not "fixed energy's vector". This means this energy flows in a fixed direction (like blood in your body always flows from arteries to veins). It's a common belief that there is a constant flow of mana in one's body, right?
- **精神感応触媒**: "Spirit-responsive catalyst". This refers to something like (non-disposable) magic items (e.g., wands, talismans, crystals) in general. Just as a stereotypical wizard needs a wand to release the mana in the body, an item that works as catalyst (reaction booster) is needed to control the 霊子 in the body. "Catalyst" is a word rarely used in occultic contexts, but it's a relatively easy word in chemistry. "Telepathy" may not be a good translation because this has nothing to do with communicating with others.
- **物理現象などに対し作用して不可思議な事象を起こす**: This is a basic explanation of magic or supernatural power in general. For example, psychokinesis causes a mysterious phenomena by acting on the physical phenomenon ruled by the law of gravity.

Comment: finally an expert came to the rescue ,so this is like "Chakra explanation episode in Naruto" not magic like i thought at first . I wonder what kind of made-up bullshit terms this writer would throw at me in the future ....